# How to create misty slowly fading horizon

Tags: unity-game-engine

I know I can cut off rendering at certain distance by fixing the far clipping plane in the camera settings. Before cutting the rendering I want to create misty looking fade of the horizon similar to the one in the following image:

[image]

I don't think that is made with Unity's fog so is it maybe an image effect? I've been googling without success since I don't know what to google.

Comment: Why do you think it's not fog?

Comment: I think that's a volumetric fog effect. You can find these in the assetstore or make your own.

Comment: I thought it's not fog because I've never been able to get the fog to look like that. Also it makes a nice hit on mobile performance. Well, now I know what to search for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That sort of effect is called "aerial perspective", or "atmospheric perspective", and is indeed generally accomplished with a volumetric fog effect.